# Block MySQL reads while updating

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I have two simple queries one reading and one updating a table. How can I lock the read for the select query while the update one is running. Right now in MySQL InnoDB I noticed that the write/update is by default locked but the read/select is getting the old data before the transaction.

I tried using a transaction in the update query and then `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` - outside of the transaction - but it didnt seem to do the trick. Also I was wondering, for testing purposes, how to slow down the UPDATE query. I came across SLEEP(X), but I dont know how to implement it inside the update query.

How can I make every query wait read/write until a write is completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `READ-COMMITTED` transaction will view the latest committed. changes, and using `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` will make the read block until any outstanding updates are committed.

Try this. In one screen, start a transaction and an UPDATE. No SLEEP() required, just don't commit the transaction. The lock created by the UPDATE will continue to exist until you commit.

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE MyTable SET something = '1234' WHERE id = 3;
```

Don't commit yet.

Meanwhile, in a second screen, set your transaction isolation to read-committed transaction. No need to start an explicit transaction, because InnoDB queries use a transaction, even if it's auto-commit.

```
SET tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = 3 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
<hangs>
```

The LOCK IN SHARE MODE makes it wait because there's still an outstanding exclusive lock created by the UPDATE.

In the first screen:

```
COMMIT;
```

In the second screen, voila! The blocking read becomes unblocked, and you immediately see the result of the UDPATE without having to refresh your transaction.

Comment: Indeed, I tested it and it works, if you dont mind, could you swiftly explain me one or two things. First of all why `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` didnt work?
Secondly I tried without `SET tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';` and it still worked. Lastly does a commit make it unable only to write till its done (isnt that by default though). I know some of them can be answered by googling, but I did so and wanted to clear them up a bit if you dont mind spending a bit of your time.

Comment: `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` should work just the same, I guess you did the steps in a different order. I don't know.

Comment: The read-committed mode will act just like repeatable-read if you use autocommit, because every statement starts a new transaction. But if you do SELECT as part of a longer transaction you'll want to use read-committed.

Comment: COMMIT releases the lock held by the UPDATE. Locks are held as long as the transaction lasts.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful :)